# Ts Error : A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value. when return statements are inside a subscribe method

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I've made a simple service in my Angular 2 project for checking if the user is logged in or not. It checks if the user object exists within the FirebaseAuth object. But the function declaration throws an error for the "lack of return statement" when actually my return statements are inside the subscribe method on the auth variable. Code looks something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit , Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseAuthState, FirebaseAuth} from "angularfire2";
@Injectable()
export class CheckLogged {

constructor(private auth:FirebaseAuth ){}
check(): boolean{
    this.auth.subscribe((user: FirebaseAuthState) => {
        if (user) {
            return true;  
        }
        return false;
    })
  }
}
```

The "check():boolean" statement throws this error

Im calling my function inside an OnInit lifecycle hook in a component
and assigning it to a variable

```
this.loggedIn = this.CheckLogged.check();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  check(): boolean{ // <<<== no boolean is returned from this function
    this.auth.subscribe((user: FirebaseAuthState) => {
        if (user) {
            return true;  
        }
        return false;
    })
  }
```

In above code `return xxx` only returns from the callback passed to `subscribe(...)`, but doesn't return from `check`.

You can't switch from async back to sync.
The method should look like

```
  check(): Observable<boolean>{ // <<<== no boolean is returned from this function
    return this.auth.map((user: FirebaseAuthState) => {
        if (user) {
            return true;  
        }
        return false;
    })
  }
```

and then the caller needs to subscribe to the return value.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work :)

Comment: This gave me an error 'map is not a function'. I needed to do the equivalent of `return this.auth.pipe(map( ....`. Not sure why, maybe to avoid conflict with the EcmaScript `map`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668701/what-is-pipe-for-in-rxjs

Comment: Probably changes in RxJS 6. I haven't used that myself yet.