# What is pipe for in RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I think I have the base concept, but there are some obscurities

So in general this is how I use an `Observable`:

```js
observable.subscribe(x => {

})
```

If I want to filter data I can use this:

```js
import { first, last, map, reduce, find, skipWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
observable.pipe(
    map(x => {return x}),
    first()
    ).subscribe(x => {

})
```

I can also do this:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

observable.map(x => {return x}).first().subscribe(x => {

})
```

So my questions are:

1. What is the difference?
2. If there is no difference, why the function `pipe` exists?
3. Why those functions need different imports?

Comment: I was about to say that it's for custom, non-native, operators, but I don't even know if that's right.  Does `pipe()` let you pass operators that you create?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The "pipeable" (former "lettable") operators is **the current and recommended way** of using operators since RxJS 5.5.

I strongly recommend you to read the [official documentation on pipeable operators](https://v6.rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators)

The main difference is that it's easier to make custom operators and that it's better treeshakable while not altering some global `Observable` object that could possible make collisions if two different parties wanted to create an operator of the same name.

Using separate `import` statement for each operator `'rxjs/add/operator/first'` was a way to make smaller app bundles. By importing only operators you need instead of the entire RxJS library you can significantly reduce the total bundle size. However the compiler can't know if you imported `'rxjs/add/operator/first'` because you really need it in you code or you just forgot to remove it when refactoring your code. That's one of the advantages of using pipeable operators where unused imports are ignored automatically.

Comment: About your affirmation `unused imports are ignored automatically`, currently the IDEs have plugins that remove unused imports.

Comment: Not everyone is using these IDEs or these plugins, many people use basic text editor. Probably most of the time we cannot relay on the statement that every one in the team is using the same IDE/plugin set/text editor as we are.

Comment: @AdamFaryna sure, some teams may also write code on paper, but why would they if they have modern tools available? Using a text editor, especially without the important plugins is similar to writing code on paper. You can do that but why would any decent team/developer do that

Comment: @DenesPapp code editor doesn't matter as long people can use it in productive way. Other than that, it's just personal preferences. Your analogy to writing code on paper is inaccurate, you cannot execute code on paper but code written in any text editor can be executed.

Comment: I didn't want to start a debate about editors, but just one note: my analogy was about static analysis, you don't get the help of static analysis and other smart tools when you use a text editor or write on paper. Running the code is a different story imo, it's not related to editors at all

Comment: Tools like TSLint should warn you automatically about unused imports, no matter what editor you use if you set the tools up to check the code automatically in the background (e.g. in githooks or continuosly, or integrated right into the editor)

Comment: QUSTION: Are there is a still way to use the old school operators style without the `pipe` operator?

Comment: @perymimon You can but you have to install `rxjs-compat` package https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#rxjs-v5x-to-v6-update-guide

Comment: The link in the answer gives 404. Here is another link: https://rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators

Comment: @Drew Also 404.

Comment: Examples in official website are not real world examples and I cannot understand most of them

Answer (score 26):

**The pipe method**

[According to original Documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators)

the pipable operator is that **function take observables** as a input and it returns another observable .previous observable stays unmodified.

```
pipe(...fns: UnaryFunction<any, any>[]): UnaryFunction<any, any>
```

[Original Post](https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44)

> What pipe mean?
>
> That means that any operators you previously used on the instance of
>   observable are available as pure functions under `rxjs/operators`.
>   This makes building a composition of operators or re-using operators
>   becomes really easy, without having to resort to all sorts of
>   programming gymnastics where you have to create a custom observable
>   extending Observable, then overwrite lift just to make your own custom
>   thing.

```
const { Observable } = require('rxjs/Rx')
const { filter, map, reduce,  } = require('rxjs/operators')
const { pipe } = require('rxjs/Rx')

const filterOutWithEvens = filter(x => x % 2)
const doubleByValue = x => map(value => value * x);
const sumValue = reduce((acc, next) => acc + next, 0);
const source$ = Observable.range(0, 10)

source$.pipe(
  filterOutWithEvens, 
  doubleByValue(2), 
  sumValue)
  .subscribe(console.log); // 50
```

Comment: @VladKuts change codes and given attributes .sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even realize I could store pipe-able operators as function references and use them in the pipe() call. That's much cleaner than always doing it inline.

Answer (score 22):

**What is the difference?**
As you see in your example, the main difference is to improve the readability of the source code. There are only two functions in your example, but imagine if there are a dozen of the functions? then it will go like

`function1().function2().function3().function4()`

it's really getting ugly, and difficult to read, especially when you are filling inside of the functions. On top of that certain editors like Visual Studio code doesn't allow more than 140 line length. but if it goes like following.

```
Observable.pipe(
function1(),
function2(),
function3(),
function4()
)
```

This drastically improves the readability.

**If there is no difference, why the function pipe exists?**
The purpose of the PIPE() function is to *lump together* all the functions that take, and return observable. It takes an observable initially, then that observable is used throughout the pipe() function by each function used inside of it.

First function takes the observable, processes it, modify its value, and passes to the next function, then next function takes the output observable of the first function, processes it, and passes to the next function, then it goes on until all the functions inside of pipe() function use that observable, finally you have the processed observable. At the end you can execute the observable with subscribe() function to extract the value out of it. Remember, the values in the original observable are not changed.!!

**Why those functions need different imports?**
Imports depend on in where the function is specified in the rxjs package. 
It goes like this. All the modules are stored in node_modules folder in Angular. 
import { class } from "module";

Let's take the following code as an example. I have just wrote it in stackblitz. So nothing is automatically generated, or copied from somewhere else. I don't see the point of copying what stated in rxjs documentation when you can go and read it too. I assume you asked this question here, because you didn't understand the documentation.

- There are pipe, observable, of, map classes imported from the
  respective modules.
- In body of the class, I used the Pipe() function
  as seen in the code.
- The Of() function returns an observable, that
  emits numbers in sequence when it's subscribed.
- Observable isn't subscribed yet.
- When you used it likes Observable.pipe(), the pipe() function uses the given Observable as an input.
- The first function, map() function uses that Observable, process it, return the processed Observable back to the pipe() function,
- then that processed Observable is given to the next function if there is any,
- and it goes on like that until all the functions process the Observable,
- at the end that Observable is returned by the pipe() function to a variable, in the following example its obs.

Now the thing in Observable is, As long as the observer didn't subscribe it, it doesn't emit any value. So I used the subscribe() function to subscribe to this Observable, then as soon as I subscribed it. The of() function starts emitting values, then they are processed through pipe() function, and you get the final result at the end, for instance 1 is taken from of() function, 1 is added 1 in map() function, and returned back. You can get that value as an argument inside of the subscribe( function (**argument**) {} ) function.

If you want to print it, then uses as

```
subscribe( function (argument) {
    console.log(argument)
   } 
)
```

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
    
      obs = of(1,2,3).pipe(
      map(x => x + 1),
      ); 
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(){  
        this.obs.subscribe(value => console.log(value))
      }
    }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-plifkg

Comment: Don't know. I like the first approach more. It looks much cleaner to me and more logical.

Comment: First approach?

Comment: I'm the same.  fn().fn().fn() looks fine.  There are heaps of good reasons for pipes, but I don't think readability is really improved.
An argument I like better is that dot notation is for object properties and functions and is artificial in that context.
Mathematically the function should be fn4(fn3(fn2(fn1())))
Now _That_ is ugly.

Comment: You can also say beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @DonDilanga The pipable operator is that function that takes observables as an input and it returns another observable .previous observable stay unmodified. - this an important point for pipe operator.

Comment: @ChaosCrafter If it makes you feel better, you can always collect and compose: 1) implement: `const compose = (fns) => fns.reduce((fn, composition) => (...args) => composition(fn(...args)))`, 2) use! `const composition = compose([fn4, ... , fn1])`. Bonus if you might want to compose in reverse: `const pipe = compose(fns.reverse())`

Answer (score 16):

A good summary I've come up with is:

It decouples the streaming operations (map, filter, reduce...) from the core functionality(subscribing, piping). By piping operations instead of chaining, it doesn't pollute the prototype of Observable making it easier to do tree shaking.

See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#why

> Problems with the patched operators for dot-chaining are:
>
> Any library that imports a patch operator will augment the
>   Observable.prototype for all consumers of that library, creating blind
>   dependencies. If the library removes their usage, they unknowingly
>   break everyone else. With pipeables, you have to import the operators
>   you need into each file you use them in.
>
> Operators patched directly onto the prototype are not "tree-shakeable"
>   by tools like rollup or webpack. Pipeable operators will be as they
>   are just functions pulled in from modules directly.
>
> Unused operators that are being imported in apps cannot be detected
>   reliably by any sort of build tooling or lint rule. That means that
>   you might import scan, but stop using it, and it's still being added
>   to your output bundle. With pipeable operators, if you're not using
>   it, a lint rule can pick it up for you.
>
> Functional composition is awesome. Building your own custom operators
>   becomes much, much easier, and now they work and look just like all
>   other operators from rxjs. You don't need to extend Observable or
>   override lift anymore.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I explain observable:

You need to make a plan based on weather conditions so you turn on a radio and listening to a weather channel that broadcasts weather conditions 24/7. In this scenario, instead of getting one single response, the response is ongoing. This response is like a subscription to an observable. the observable is the "weather" and the subscription is the "radio signals that keep you updated". As long as your radio is on, you are getting every available update. You are not missing any information until you turn off the radio.

I said weather is observable, but you are listening to the radio not the weather. So the radio is also an observable. What the weather announcer says is the function of the weather report sent to him by the meteorologist. What meteorologist writes is a function of data coming from the weather station. The data is coming from the weather station is the function of all the instruments (barometer, wind wane, wind gauge) attached to it and the instruments are a function of the weather itself.

There are at least 5 observables in this entire process. In this process, there are two types of observables. Source observable and output observable. In this example, the weather is the "source observable" and the radio is the "output observable". Everything in between represents the `PIPE FUNCTION`.

**Pipe function** is what takes the source observable performs operations on it to provide an output observable and all of those operations happen inside. The operations all deal with the observables themselves

Comment: Seem like a good story - But, I felt like it complicated it for me.  Im sure it will help others.

Comment: This doesn't explain why you would use the pipe function vs. constructing the observable by calling `map`, `first`, etc. on the Observable objects directly. Other implementations of Rx, e.g. RxJava, do not need a pipe function.