# Preserving original properties in Typecript object class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I preserve the original properties of a class object when mapping with the new object.

Let's say I have a class with the following property.

```
export class User{
 public name: string;
 public age: number;
 public internalId: number;
}
```

Following is where I am assigning values from call back subscribe() function

```
this.userService.getUnratedJobNotification().subscribe(
            (data)=>{
                if(data && data.length > 0){
                    this.User = data;
                }
        });
```

Now the data I receive from service only contains a name and age. Not internalId property.

After assigning via subscribe function, I only left with name and age.

I don't really know if this question was answered before or at least I don't really know what the right way to ask.

Comment: Which I will assign later, maybe numbers. 1st I load this data, then render HTML elements, based on users interaction with each set of the object I will flag the internalId. which then be processed for submission based on this flag.

Answer (score 2):

With Object.assign.

```
this.User = Object.assign({}, this.User, data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy all properties from your returned object into an actual `User` object.

I recommend using RxJS' [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator before subscribing:

```
this.userService.getUnratedJobNotification().pipe(
  map(data => Object.assign(new User(), data))
).subscribe((user: User) => {
  this.User = user;
});
```

Comment: So what does this pipe do?

Comment: `pipe` is how you apply RxJS operators to your observables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668701/what-is-pipe-for-in-rxjs.

Comment: Still, it over writes the original class properties.

Comment: Not sure to follow. Can you maybe create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I mean, what I want is after observable call, I should see the original property `internalId` so that I can later use it for submition back to API. if this property is not there, I cannot actually submit since this will throw property not found exception.

Comment: What do you mean "original property `internalId`"? You can assign `this.User.internalId` to whatever you'd like using this code, including `null`. What exactly are you expecting the object's value to be?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqsp62 I just copied my code in the stackblitz but I was not able to extract the running condition. Have a look.

Comment: I mean the the Angular Class does have the `internalid` property in it. but the service I am calling will return with only two properies, such as name and age. So when I assign it to a member variable, I don't see them

Comment: You don't see "them"? You mean `internalId`? That's because it's undefined since your service won't return any value for it. If you want to force it as `null`, you can do this instead: `map(data => Object.assign(new User(), {internalId: null}, data))` <- check my edit there.

Comment: Yes, `internalId` is missing. Also what if I have many properties that I wanna keep it the same way? Only way is using this anonymous class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191776/discussion-between-jeto-and-kirk).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [lodash merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge) to deal with complex entities:

```
var object = {
  'a': [{ 'b': 2 }, { 'd': 4 }]
};

var other = {
  'a': [{ 'c': 3 }, { 'e': 5 }]
};

_.merge(object, other);
// => { 'a': [{ 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }, { 'd': 4, 'e': 5 }] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.User = data;` with `this.User = {...this.User, ...data};`

```js
this.userService.getUnratedJobNotification().subscribe(
  data => {
    if (data) {
      this.User = { ...this.User, ...data };
    }
  });
```

Comment: I removed the check `data.length > 0` because an object does not have `length` property.