# SwitchMap is not working as intended in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, webstorm

I tried building an CMS app in Angular 5 using Firebase but getting an error in switch map and User interface

1. `switchmap()` unresolvable function or method.
2. Initializer type `uid`, `email` etc. can't be assigned to variable type `User`

**af.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from './user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AfService {
  user$: Observable<User>;
  constructor( public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
               public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState.switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/$(user.uid)`).valueChanges();
      } else {
        return of(null);
      }
    });
  }
    loginWithGoogle() {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((credential) => {
        this.updateUser(credential.user);
      });
    }
  updateUser(user) {
      const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/$(user.uid)`);
      const data: User = {
        uid: User.id,
        email: User.email,
        roles: {
          subscriber: true,
          admin: false
        }
      }
      return userRef.set(data, {merge: true});
  }
    logout() {
      this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    }
}
```

**user.ts**

```
export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  displayName: string;
  roles: Roles;
}

export interface Roles {
  subscriber?: boolean;
  admin?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Which version of AngularFire are you using? It may be that you need to use the new syntax using `pipe`.

Comment: Also, your attempted instantiation of a `User` in `updateUser` looks wrong. I think you mean to use `userRef` and not `User` inside the object, plus it's missing a `displayName` member

Comment: @WillAlexander I'm still getting error while using userRef ,and I think that it's not important to call all the member like displayName(correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: to answer your latest question, if you have declared displayName as a required prop, you need to add it to your payload, if not, make it optional.

Comment: If your object doesn't contain all of the necessary fields, it doesn't implement the interface correctly.

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks it helped a little! But I'm still getting error 'User' only refers to a type,but is being used as a value here.

Comment: @HelloStack, did you check my answer?

Comment: @AJT_82: Yes I marked displayName as optional field.

Comment: @HelloStack But did you look at my answer, below this comment section? You have other issues too.

Comment: @AJT_82 Now getting promise rejection at RunTime


Unhandled Promise rejection: Missing or insufficient permissions. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:107908:28)

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks!!!! It worked:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some issues, you are importing switchMap in a way that it should be used inside `pipe`. Also you have typos (?): `$(user.uid)` should be `${user.uid}`. Also you are passing `user` to your `updateUser` function, but you are using the **type** `User` in your payload. Also, you need to include `displayName` in your payload, since you have made it required. Sooooo....

Change the round brackets to curly on both places (`updateUser()` and `authState`):

```ts
return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
```

Then set `switchMap` inside [`pipe()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48668943/6294072):

```ts
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
            return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
            return of(null);
        }
    })
);
```

Change the payload for the `updateUser`:

```ts
const data: User = {
  uid: user.uid, // should be uid, not id!
  email: user.email,
  displayName: user.displayName
  roles: <Roles>{
    subscriber: true,
    admin: false
  }
}
```